# Transition of multi-core processor from real mode to protected mode in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86-64, boot, bootloader

I'm trying to learn more about operating systems and I am currently taking a look how the Linux kernel is loaded and initialized.

Thanks to several related questions and [this book](https://0xax.gitbooks.io/linux-insides/), I was mostly able to understand how the [transition from real mode to protected mode](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/024ddc0ce1049298bd3cae60ae45d9c5f0fb8b9c/arch/x86/boot/pmjump.S#L26) works.

However, the one thing I don't understand is, how and when the rest of the cores are switched to protected mode for multi-core processors (as far as I know, every core has its own set of control registers and the switch seems only to happen once in the booting process).

<s>(I only found [this somehow related question with an (short) answer](https://superuser.com/q/1126634) that it is not possible to have two cores in different modes, however there was no source given.)</s> This answer is wrong (thanks to e.g. [n.m.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-m) in the comments for pointing that out).

**Edit:** As the comments already pointed out, the kernel might do this later in the initialization process, however when does that happen?

Comment: That comment is wrong.

Comment: Most boot programs for various processor arches would boot the kernel in the same mode that the processor has when started.  That means that a multi-core processor chip would be in single-core mode, and it's up to the kernel to enable the other processors.  Usually there's no rush to to enable the other cores during boot, as the kernel initialization is typically single threaded.

Comment: Yes, every core has its own control registers and can be in different modes.  My understanding is that the boot core detects how many other cores there are *after* entering protected mode.  Linux's switch-to-protected-mode (and then long mode) happens very early.  Then I think Linux on the boot core sets up stuff like GDT, IDT, and page tables for the other cores and pokes whatever hardware is necessary to cause each other core to start running code in the same mode as the boot kernel.  *I think*.  Linux can run user-space code in other modes, but uses long mode or legacy mode in the kernel.

Comment: On more recent kernels the answer would be both (older kernels were done early in the SMP boot process). Kernels that support hotplug CPUs can spin up CPUs as needed while the OS is running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the input by [sawdust](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1599004/sawdust), [Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes) and [Michael Petch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3857942/michael-petch) I was able to find the solution to my question (here for Linux v4.16):

Basically the transition from real mode to protected mode happens on every startup of a core (if hotplug is supported, that can happen at any time).

The first time a startup of a secondary processor happens, is during the [SMP (Symmetric Multiprocessing) initialization](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/024ddc0ce1049298bd3cae60ae45d9c5f0fb8b9c/kernel/smp.c#L563) (which is part of the kernel initialization). There, `cpu_up()` is called for all CPUs present during initialization:

```
for_each_present_cpu(cpu) {
  if (num_online_cpus() >= setup_max_cpus)
    break;
  if (!cpu_online(cpu))
    cpu_up(cpu); // Startup of the core in the following functions
}
```

This function call is leading to the activation of the cores using [APIC](https://wiki.osdev.org/APIC) (see INIT/SIPI signals).

At first, the woken cores are in real mode and get the [real mode trampoline code for x86-64](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/0adb32858b0bddf4ada5f364a84ed60b196dbcda/arch/x86/realmode/rm/trampoline_64.S#L41) as an entry point,
in the case of x86-64.

There and in the following functions, the transition to [protected mode](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/0adb32858b0bddf4ada5f364a84ed60b196dbcda/arch/x86/realmode/rm/trampoline_64.S#L74) for secondary processors happens (e.g. setting the PE bit):

```
# Enable protected mode
movl  $X86_CR0_PE, %eax  # protected mode (PE) bit
movl  %eax, %cr0         # into protected mode
```